# Cannot add localnotification plugin to android phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried this [localnotificationplugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification) for adding local notification plugin and worked each step as in read me although I had some compilation errors but I resolved that by changing `alarm = new AlarmHelper(this.ctx);`in localnotification.java with `new AlarmHelper(cordova.getContext());` here is my localnotification.js

```
    /*-
 * Phonegap LocalNotification Plugin for Android
 *
 * Created by Daniel van 't Oever 2012 MIT Licensed
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 * plugins.localNotification.add({ date: new Date(), message: 'This is an Android alarm using the statusbar', id: 123 });
 * plugins.localNotification.cancel(123);
 * plugins.localNotification.cancelAll();
 *
 * This interface is similar to the existing iOS LocalNotification plugin created by Greg Allen
 */
if (typeof PhoneGap !== "undefined") {

    /**
     * Empty constructor
     */
    var LocalNotification = function() {
    };

    /**
     * Register a notification message for a specific date / time
     * 
     * @param successCB
     * @param failureCB
     * @param options
     *            Array with arguments. Valid arguments are date, message,
     *            repeatDaily and id
     */
    LocalNotification.prototype.add = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            date : new Date(),
            message : '',
            ticker : '',
            repeatDaily : false,
            id : ""
        };

        if (options.date) {
            options.date = (options.date.getMonth()) + "/"
                    + (options.date.getDate()) + "/"
                    + (options.date.getFullYear()) + "/"
                    + (options.date.getHours()) + "/"
                    + (options.date.getMinutes());
        }

        for ( var key in defaults) {
            if (typeof options[key] !== "undefined")
                defaults[key] = options[key];
        }

        PhoneGap.exec(null, null, 'LocalNotification', 'add', new Array(
                defaults));
    };

    /**
     * Cancel an existing notification using its original ID.
     * 
     * @param id
     *            The ID that was used when creating the notification using the
     *            'add' method.
     */
    LocalNotification.prototype.cancel = function(notificationId) {
        PhoneGap.exec(null, null, 'LocalNotification', 'cancel', new Array({
            id : notificationId
        }));
    };

    /**
     * Cancel all notifications that were created by your application.
     */
    LocalNotification.prototype.cancelAll = function() {
        PhoneGap
                .exec(null, null, 'LocalNotification', 'cancelAll', new Array());
    };

    /**
     * Register this plugin with phonegap
     */
    PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
        alert("constructor called here");
        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        }
        window.plugins.localNotification = new LocalNotification();
        alert("localnotification called");
    });
}
```

It calls to phonegap constructor and  alert("localnotification called"); is shown but after that add is not executed thus, I Cannot get localnotification to run

Answer (score 0):

Where are you testing it (device or emulator)? You know that the localnotification don't popup a window, don't you?
Is there any error in the Log?